# Google Adwords reports error

Tags: java

We are using Google ad-libs v201506 jar. While downloading google adwords reports, intermittently we get the error

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute "lang" associated with an element type "html".`

I see that response code is 502 ( bad gateway ) and it appears that the parser is trying to parse the error message from the HTTP response and fails.

Has anyone using the this library seen this error or know a way to fix this?

Comment: 502 is indicating a severe server error on the Google side, thus any subsequent operation on client side must fail if that's not catched. Can you log and post the original request to adwords? Usually the lib is creating some logs in the root of the app if not turned off explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

[An "AdWords API Forum" thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/adwords-api@googlegroups.com/msg26303.html) from 2013 indicates that one person solved a similar issue by changing from the AdWords sandbox environment to production.

Comment: Yes, I have read through that forum. 2 things are different in my case. 
1. In the forum thread, the user posted the response error as 503 ( as opposed to 502 in my case ) and 2.  I do not get this error in sand box environment, I am getting this in actual production logs.